# Update the highest auto incremented primary key in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to update the latest data, or the highest ID.

MAX function doesn't seem to work on update.

edit:

```
UPDATE table SET name='test_name' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

seems to work. but im not sure if its really the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE table
SET field = yourvalue
WHERE Id = (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM table)
```

Answer (score 0):

you looking for `LAST_INSERT_ID()`

```
 Update table SET name='test_name'
 where id = LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

Comment: There are many use cases, where `LAST_INSERT_ID()` will give wrong result.

Comment: Try this (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88e4c/1) and let me know what you think about this.